# Unable to run Docker command

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtualbox, docker-for-windows

I have installed **Docker for Windows**, and trying the run a simple command, but I am getting the below error:

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.29/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Update:**

I just reinstalled Docker on my machine (Windows 10), but now I am getting a VirtualBox error. Anything I am missing here?

`Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to create a network adapter. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Assertion failed: [!aInterfaceName.isEmpty()] at 'F:\tinderbox\win-5.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\HostNetworkInterfaceImpl.cpp' (74) in long __cdecl HostNetworkInterface::init(class com::Bstr,class com::Bstr,class com::Guid,enum __MIDL___MIDL_itf_VirtualBox_0000_0000_0038).
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Please contact the product vendor!
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default)
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking status on default´... Press any key to continue...`

Comment: So you docker is not properly installed or not running. The error message is pretty cleared. Fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems your docker daemon is not running. Please start your docker as service.Please use this as reference: https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/StartDockerDaemonAsAWindowsService.html